# Bokeh: CustomJS Callback for Mouse Move or Click

Tags: javascript, python, plot, bokeh

I want to update my plot data based on the current mouse position.

What I'm aiming for is something like the [interactive power function plot](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#customjs-for-widgets), but instead of taking the exponent from a slider, take the exponent to be the current x-value of the mouse cursor (in plot coordinate space, not display coordinates).

If it's not possible to get an onMouseMove callback, onClick would also be ok. However, I don't want to have to click a specific graph (then I could use TapTool), but tapping anywhere in the plot should suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HoverTool and CustomJS as in the code example below. This example plots a line from the cursor position to the (1,1) point. When opening a JavaScript Console, you can see the values of x and y as you move the mouse.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure,show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, HoverTool
import numpy as np

s = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x=[0,1],y=[0,1])) #points of the line
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(s=s), code="""
        var geometry = cb_data['geometry'];
        var x_data = geometry.x; // current mouse x position in plot coordinates
        var y_data = geometry.y; // current mouse y position in plot coordinates
        console.log("(x,y)=" + x_data+","+y_data); //monitors values in Javascript console
        var x = s.get('data')['x'];
        var y = s.get('data')['y'];
        x[0] = x_data;
        y[0] = y_data;
        s.trigger('change');
    """)
hover_tool = HoverTool(callback=callback)
p = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1), tools= [hover_tool,
                        "crosshair,box_zoom,wheel_zoom,pan,reset"])
p.line(x='x',y='y',source=s)
show(p)
```

[image]

Output of the Javascript console:

```
...
VM615:7 (x,y)=0.37494791666666666,0.37447916666666664
VM615:7 (x,y)=0.37494791666666666,0.37114583333333334
VM615:7 (x,y)=0.37161458333333336,0.37114583333333334
VM615:7 (x,y)=0.38828125,0.37114583333333334
VM615:7 (x,y)=0.43161458333333336,0.3878125
VM615:7 (x,y)=0.7216145833333333,0.4878125
...
```

Comment: This works well for mouse position but could the CustomJS be adapted for clicks? Thanks!

Comment: You can use TapTool to react to click events over glyphs. See an example in my answer attempt here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640536/bokeh-how-to-make-hovertool-tooltips-stick-to-points-on-click