# Bokeh - how to make HoverTool tooltips stick to points on click?

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bokeh

The code below comes from a [jupyter notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/draperjames/PythonRef/blob/master/Bokeh%20HoverTool%20Custom%20ToolTips.ipynb):

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Range1d

output_notebook()
fig = figure(tools=[HoverTool(tooltips=[("html", '@html{safe}')])])

fig.quad(left="left", top="top", bottom="bottom", right="right",
         source=ColumnDataSource({"left": [1,3], "bottom": [1,3],
                                  "right": [2,4], "top": [2,4],
                                  "html":["<b>I'm bold</b>", "<span 

style='color:red;font-size:32px;'>BIG RED TEXT</span>"]}))
    show(fig)
```

I need to make the HoverTool tooltips stick to exactly where they are on a clicking the point, so if a user wanted to highlight the and copy the text in the tooltip they could. This [codepen](http://codepen.io/drapja/pen/MJyxvv) has an example of the type of behavior I would like to see. I know that this must be possible by either injecting some type of CustomJS or altering [BokehJS coffescript](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/d2ce1971e4b984c7d30728b2378f7c959a3efd06/bokehjs/src/coffee/models/annotations/tooltip.coffee) and building BokehJS from scratch but I haven't been able to figure it out. Does anybody out there have any idea how to do this?

UPDATE:
It might be possible to a create a [custom tool](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/tool.html#userguide-extensions-examples-tool) using the [tap_tool.coffee](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokehjs/src/coffee/models/tools/gestures/tap_tool.coffee), [hover_tool.coffee](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokehjs/src/coffee/models/tools/inspectors/hover_tool.coffee) or [tooltip.coffee](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokehjs/src/coffee/models/annotations/tooltip.coffee). I'll update this if I figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround creating your own Hover text using `models.Label` inside the 'callback' function of `models.HoverTool` . Also `models.TapTool` is used for toggle updating the Label text. You can't edit the text in the glyph `models.Label`, but an `TextInput` `widget` has been added where the text is updated as one hover the graph glyphs.

```
import bokeh
import bokeh.plotting
fig = bokeh.plotting.figure()

d_source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource({"left": [1,3,1],
                "bottom": [1,3,3],"right": [2,4,2],"top": [2,4,4]})
h_source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource({"do_hover":[True,True]  })
fig.quad(left="left", top="top", bottom="bottom", right="right",
         source=d_source)

myToolTip = bokeh.models.Label(x=2.5,y=2.5, text="",
                               background_fill_color = "#ffffff")

HoverCallback = bokeh.models.CustomJS(args=dict(d_source=d_source,
                    myToolTip=myToolTip,h_source=h_source),code="""
        function findWhereIam(x,y,s){
            // To find where the cursor is. 
            selection = -1;
            for (i = 0; i < s.data.left.length; i++) {
                x0 = s.data.left[i];
                x1 = s.data.right[i];
                y0 = s.data.bottom[i];
                y1 = s.data.top[i];
                if (x>x0 && x<x1 && y>y0 && y<y1){
                    // It's inside rectangle!!!
                    selection = i;
                }
            }
            return selection
        }
        if (h_source.data.do_hover[0]){
            x_data = cb_data['geometry'].x;
            y_data = cb_data['geometry'].y;
            var selection = findWhereIam(x_data,y_data,d_source)
            if (selection>=0){
                x0 = d_source.data.left[selection];
                x1 = d_source.data.right[selection];
                y0 = d_source.data.bottom[selection];
                y1 = d_source.data.top[selection];
                myToolTip.x = 0.5 * (x0+x1);
                myToolTip.y = 0.5 * (y0+y1);
                myToolTip.text = "on:"+selection;
                myToolTip.text_font_size = "24pt";
                myToolTip.background_fill_color = "#ffffff";
                myToolTip.border_line_color = "#000000";
                myToolTip.text_align = "center";
                myToolTip.trigger('change');

                current_selection.value = myToolTip.text;
                current_selection.trigger('change');
            }else{
                myToolTip.text = ""; //erase
                myToolTip.trigger('change');
                current_selection.value = myToolTip.text;
                current_selection.trigger('change');
            }
        }
    """)

TapCallback = bokeh.models.CustomJS(args=dict(h_source=h_source), code="""
        h_source.data.do_hover[0] = !h_source.data.do_hover[0];
    """)

current_selection = bokeh.models.widgets.TextInput(value="",
                                                   title="Selection")

HoverCallback.args.update(dict(current_selection=current_selection))

fig.add_tools(bokeh.models.HoverTool(tooltips=None,callback=HoverCallback))
fig.add_tools(bokeh.models.TapTool(callback=TapCallback))
fig.add_layout(myToolTip)
page = bokeh.plotting.gridplot([[fig],[current_selection]])
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
bokeh.io.show(page)
```

[image]

Comment: this is fantastic thank you! If you happen to have any thoughts later on how to allow the text to be selected please let me know.

Comment: Well, you can create an `InputText` widget that is updated as you hover over glyphs. I've just added that feature in my answer. The `InputText` `widget` is editable, so you can copy it's value to the clipboard.

Comment: I was wondering how you would set the findWhereIAm function for a barplot of categorical data. An example would be https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html