# Extract values from a plot by mouse in bokeh

Tags: bokeh, interactive

I have a function y=f(x,a,b), where x,y are the independent and dependent variables and a,b are parameters.

I want to generate a two-panel figure [A,B], where A is the a-versus-b parameter space and B is the y-versus-x function line. I want to be able to use the mouse (say, by hovering over) in panel A to select a pair of (a,b) values and then update the y--x line in the panel B correspondingly.

What widget/method I need to achieve this? I did some research on [bokeh hover tool](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool) but it generates a tooltip instead of a panel plot, plus I don't know how to extract the values from mouse other than the tooltips syntax in hover tool.

PS: I know this can be achieved by using two sliders (one for a, one for b), but using a panel and mouse gives more flexibility in probing the a-b phase space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PARTIAL SOLUTION

I found a very similar question [with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323343/5426033) on how to extract the value from the mouse hover tool. Combined with another [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html) about changing a subplot from a callback in a different widget/subplot, here is a working solution with some major disadvantages listing below:

```
# my test
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_notebook, show

output_notebook()

x0 = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y0 = x0
sB = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x0, y=y0))
sA = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x=[0],y=[0]))

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(sA=sA,sB=sB), code="""
    var geometry = cb_data['geometry'];
    var a = geometry.x; // current mouse x position in plot coordinates
    var b = geometry.y; // current mouse y position in plot coordinates
    var as = sA.get('data')['x'];
    var bs = sA.get('data')['y'];
    as[0] = a;
    bs[0] = b;
    sA.trigger('change');

    var data = sB.data;
    x = data['x']
    y = data['y']
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], a+b) // have to convert python function to js here!!!
    }
    sB.trigger('change');
""")

hover_tool = HoverTool(callback=callback)
A = Figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1), tools= [hover_tool,
                        "crosshair,box_zoom,wheel_zoom,pan,reset"])
A.circle(x='x',y='y',source=sA)
B = Figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1), tools= ["crosshair,box_zoom,wheel_zoom,pan,reset"])
B.line(x='x',y='y',source=sB)
layout = column(A,B)
show(layout)
```

One MAJOR DRAWBACK of this solution is that it utilizes the javascript which I'm totally unfamiliar with and that I have to convert the function `f(x,a,b)` from python to javascript. I'd appreciate any better solution that can keep the original python function `f` or other workarounds?

Comment: In order to use real python code, you'd have to write a Bokeh server app, that runs on the Bokeh server (the browser knows nothing at all about Python, the Bokeh server is what can run real Python code in callbacks). If you can confirm you are interested in a Bokeh app solution, I can take a look.

Comment: @bigreddot That sounds like what I need. I'm running jupyter notebook on a remote linux server so I guess the Bokeh server should be running remotely as well? As for the python function, it only depends on the numpy package. Hope this configuration is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the solution of your problem.

I give you the entire code :

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure,show, ColumnDataSource, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Label
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, HoverTool
import numpy as np
output_notebook()
TOOLS = "xpan,crosshair"

callback_js ="""
        var geometry = cb_data['geometry'];
        var x_data = geometry.x; // current mouse x position in plot coordinates
        var y_data = geometry.y; // current mouse y position in plot coordinates
        console.log("(x,y)=" + x_data+","+y_data); //monitors values in Javascript console
        date_label.text ='x=' + x_data.toFixed(2) + '    ' + 'y=' + y_data.toFixed(2)
        console.log(date_label.text)
    """


s = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x=[0,1],y=[0,1])) #points of the line
p = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1),tools=TOOLS)
p.line(x='x',y='y',source=s)
date_label = Label(x=30, y=30, x_units='screen', y_units='screen',
                     text='', render_mode='css',
                     border_line_color='white', border_line_alpha=1.0,
                     background_fill_color='white', background_fill_alpha=1.0)

date_label.text = ""
p.add_layout(date_label)
callback=CustomJS(args={'date_label':date_label},code=callback_js)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback))
show(p)
```

Give me a feedback if you want to improve it.

Good Coding